# what's the difference between assigning null or change value?

Tags: java

```
public class ListNode{ 
 ListNode next=null;
 int val; 
 public ListNode(int val){ this.val=val; } }

 ListNode node=new ListNode(3);
 ListNode mm=node; mm=null;
 System.out.println(node==null); -------> false

 ListNode nn=node; nn.val=100; 
 System.out.println(node.val); --------->100
```

First I assigned node to mm, but after I assigned null to mm, node did not change to null. But when I assigned node to nn, and I changed the value of nn, the value of node changes! Do you know why?

Comment: Could you format the code with markdown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between **objects** and **variables** (which "point to" or "refer to" objects).

Let's walk through your code.

### Part one

```
ListNode node=new ListNode(3);
ListNode mm=node;
mm=null;
```

---

```
ListNode node=new ListNode(3);
```

Here we have done two things:

1. We've created a new `ListNode` **object** with a `val` equal to three. This object lives out in memory, on the heap.
2. We've assigned this new **object** to the **variable** named `node`. So `node` *refers to* or *points to* this object.

```
node ---------> ListNode(val = 3)
```

---

Next,

```
ListNode mm=node;
```

Now we have another **variable** called `mm`, and it is now referring to the *same object* that `node` refers to.

```
node ---------> ListNode(val = 3) 
               /
  mm ---------/
```

---

Finally,

```
mm=null;
```

Here we say that `mm` now refers to nothing (`null`). However, the **object** in memory remains unchanged.

```
node ---------> ListNode(val = 3) 

  mm ---------> (nothing)
```

### Part two

```
ListNode nn=node;
nn.val=100;
System.out.println(node.val);  // Prints "100"
```

---

```
ListNode nn=node;
```

Again, we have another **variable** called `nn` and it is now referring to the *same object* that `node` refers to.

```
node ---------> ListNode(val = 3) 
               /
  nn ---------/
```

---

Next

```
 nn.val=100;
```

Here, we are actually saying: "Take whatever object `nn` refers to, and set his `val` member to 100."

```
node ---------> ListNode(val = 100)     [note value changed!]
               /
  nn ---------/
```

---

Lastly,

```
System.out.println(node.val);
```

Here we are saying "Take whatever object `node` refers to, and get the value of his `val` member."  But remember, `node` and `nn` are referring to the *same object*. So the change we made on the previous line is reflected by this output too!

### Conclusion

- In many programs, we may have many variables that point to one particular object. No matter which variable we use to get to that object, the changes will be made and show up via any of the variables that point to him.
- Changes to the variables *themselves* mean *nothing* to the other variables! That is why assigning `null` to `mm` had no consequence to `node`.  The only way to make an object "go away", is to ensure that there are **no remaining references** to that object. At this point it is eligible for *garbage collection*.

Answer (score 1):

`node` and `mm` are two separate variables, referencing to the same object.  When you assign null to `mm`, you're simply removing the reference to the object stored in `mm`, not affecting the object or the value stored in `node`.  On the other hand, when you change the value in the object, none of the variables that reference that object change, only the values inside the object and so when you print the value referenced by any of them, you see the updated value.